# How do I assign array of Datagridview in winform in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

I know i can assign gridview by:

```
public static DataGridView grid = new DataGridView();
```

but i want an array

Comment: Have you tried `List<GridView> ?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try:

```
DataGridView [] myArray = new DataGridView [5];
myArray[0] = new DataGridView();
// ...
```

Comment: i was needed a 2d array so i did this
    public static DataGridView[,] grid = new DataGridView[3,7];

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
List<DataGridView> Grids = new List<DataGridView>();
// Assigning new DataGridViews
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  Grids.Add(new DataGridView());
// Fetching one
DataGridView fetched = Grids[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
public static List < DataGridView >  grids = new List < DataGridView > ();
```